# VS Code Intellisense doesn't work with DOMDocument extension

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, intellisense, php-extensions

I'm working with PHP through Visual Studio Code and I need to create some XML documents. I've seen that in PHP 7.X there is and extension called [DOMDocument](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) that seems really simple and useful.
The problem is that Intellisense doesn't show any suggestions about DOMDocument extension when I type.

I checked if the extension is enabled in php through `phpinfo()` and it is.

I think I am missing something basic, but I can't figure out what it is since I don't even found anything in the Settings about this, so where's the problem?

It's really frustrating having to continuously check if the syntax is correct or not.

Thank you in advance for the help!